# What's the difference between a Magento theme and a Magento skin?

Tags: magento

What's the difference between a Magento theme and a Magento skin? What's the relationshiop between these and a Magento module?

Comment: Have you tried too Google for it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A theme is **any combination of layout, template, locale and/or skin file(s)** that create the visual experience...

A theme consists of any or all of the following:

- **Layout** (located in app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/layout/)
  These are basic XML files that define block structure for different pages as well as control META information and page encoding.For in-depth look into layouts, read Intro to Layouts)
- **Templates** (located in app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/template/)
  These are PHTML files that contain (X)HTML markups and any necessary PHP tags to create logic for visual presentation.
- **Locale** (located in app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/locale/)
  These are simple text documents organized on a per language basis that contain translations for store copy.
- **Skins** (located in skin/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/)
  These are block-specific Javascript and CSS and image files that compliment your (X)HTML.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4

Comment: The referenced into is also found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Might also want to mention the fact that in Magento there can be a number of design packages, where each design package contains one or more themes. There is a fallback mechanism, where magento searches for files in the current theme, then in the default theme for the design package, and then in the base design package for each file that needs to be fetched.

Comment: Might also want to point out that the locale directory is only for localizations that have to do with interface elements contained in the given theme.

Comment: Also, the skin directory contains files which need to be public, hence downloadable by any browser, whereas the app/design directory is for use by the server and hence can do with more restricted file permissions to enhance security on the server.

Comment: Furthermore, what you call your_interface, you could call your_designpackage since what used to called interfaces in old versions of magento are now called design packages.

Comment: Older versions of magento did not have a "base" design package (i.e. app/design/frontend/base and skin/frontend/base) on which to fall back but newer versions do, enhancing code reuse and requiring less code to be duplicated or ported from one release to the next since files in the base package can change in a way less loosely coupled with the add-on design package and templates which need not relfect such changes when they are found in the base package from one release to the next.